# Error while executing federated learning text generation tutorial in Colab

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-federated, federated-learning

I am trying to follow this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/federated_learning_for_text_generation) on federated learning TensorFlow and when executing this line I get an error:

```
train_data, test_data = tff.simulation.datasets.shakespeare.load_data()
```

The error:

```
    Downloading shakespeare.sqlite.lzma:  79%|███████▉  | 1048576/1329828 [00:00<00:00, 12187174.26it/s]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-f8f1fc62c096> in <module>()
----> 1 train_data, test_data = tff.simulation.datasets.shakespeare.load_data()

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py in _prewrite_check(self)
     86                                            "File isn't open for writing")
     87       self._writable_file = _pywrap_file_io.WritableFile(
---> 88           compat.path_to_bytes(self.__name), compat.as_bytes(self.__mode))
     89 
     90   def _prepare_value(self, val):

NotFoundError: /root/.tff/shakespeare.sqlite; No such file or directory
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OWh2.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with the current `tensorflow-federated-nightly` pip package. It should be fixed by https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/pull/1162.

In the mean time, try changing the `pip install` in the first cell to use the `tensorflow-federated` package instead of the nightly package. Example:

```py
!pip install --quiet --upgrade tensorflow_federated
!pip install --quiet --upgrade nest_asyncio

import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it worked on Colab, but on my local machine I got this: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_federated' has no attribute 'federated_computation'
Is there anything I can check for?

Comment: This might be caused by a running `python` in a directory that contains a subdirectory called `tensorflow_federated`. This would conflict with Python's [Module Search Path](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path). If such a subdirectory exists, try renaming it or running the Python interpreter from another location.